# Several containers at one page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have recently started to use Twitter Bootstrap and trying to understand how it works. I am looking at [fluid layout example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html) source code. There are two containers (div class="container-fluid"). What is the reason to use two containers instead of adding one container and several rows (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `.container-fluid` available is housing two different sections of the demo page. The first houses the top fixed navbar, which has a different responsive behavior than the rest of the content. And the second is the `.container-fluid` found in the content section, which is there to contain the main content of the page.

So to answer your question, there are two `.container-fluid` containers because of different responsive behavior on the two sections of the page.