# Twitter Bootstrap `container` divs in ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, twitter-bootstrap

I have found some info on `container` use in [Several containers at one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169455/several-containers-at-one-page) and [Twitter Bootstrap Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203614/twitter-bootstrap-containers), but was left wanting a bit more input.

From Twitter Bootstrap's own example we see multiple `container` divs on the same page.  But what about ASP.Net MasterPages and UserControls.

Should a single `container` be used on the Master, therefore enclosing all Content areas in a single top-level `container` (and then the Content pages would be comprised of `row` divs)?  Or should the `container` div be pushed down to the Content page?

And taking this one step further, what about a rather complicated UserControl (.ascx) that is comprised of several `row` divs; should the ascx markup have its own `container`, or start with a `row` div assuming the containing page has an enclosing `container`?

Finally, more generally, does anyone have a rule-of-thumb regarding when to use a new `container` div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I put the container div in my master page since all my pages will be using the row/span's in the child pages. In the unlikely event that I want my child page to not use the container, I simply close the div tags...

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  </div> <!-- ending the container -->

  <!-- whatever -->

  <div> <!-- the master page ends the container div, so we'll add this instead -->
</asp:Content>
```

A few helpful hints with bootstrap and asp.net...

**Radio buttons and checkboxes.**
The text appears underneath the radio/checkbox. Fix this by nesting your asp.net radio button list control or similar control inside a div with the `radio` css class or `checkbox` css class, and setting the RepeatLayout to flow.

```
<div class="radio">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblFleettype" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

**Alerts for error messages.**
A lot of asp.net controls can be converted to templates to expose the error literals/labels, then you can apply `CssClass="alert alert-error"` to the error label. But if you do this it will show the red error boundaries even when there is no error yet. To fix that you can use the PreRender event for the literal/label to check the `Text` property and see if it's empty, and then set the `Visibility` property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on closing the `container` on the Content page.  And great additional info on the asp.net controls.  WRT Bootstrap `container`s, do you have any feelings on whether it is ok to nest `container` divs or is it better to keep the `container` at the "outer" level?

Comment: Outer level I think. The `container` class has the `width: 940px;` property. So nesting that inside anything less than a span12 is probably not a good idea. You can nest rows inside other rows, [example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem). If you are wanting to nest a container inside some `span##`, bootstrap has `container-fluid`. You can nest away all you want with that. You can look at the usage in that link above.

Comment: Thanks much.  I have what I need now.